# How to plot different class of time series data into one panel?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, zoo

I have several product's hourly summary of multiple attributes in one table.

and I would like to plot them into one panel where x-axis stands for time and different type of products have different color.

My data looks like this:

```
> require(data.table)
# Create some data 
> dt<-data.table(type=c(rep("a",168),rep("b",168),rep("c",168)),
time=1:168,A=rnorm(168,10,5),B=rnorm(168,100,20),C=rnorm(168,10,5))
> DT  #Each type has 1~168 hours summary of all three attributes

    type time         A         B         C
  1:    a    1  7.462817 119.91299  7.404987
  2:    a    2  7.733695 146.14601 -3.203601
  3:    a    3 19.034468  84.45497  9.623048
  4:    a    4  8.813990 123.21235 12.719920
  5:    a    5 16.803735  92.69359 11.393730
 ---                                        
500:    c  164 18.016771  90.29856 10.238281
501:    c  165  6.566802 131.67801 -2.085370
502:    c  166 20.031678  83.34749 12.261008
503:    c  167  4.705976 109.76303  9.327958
504:    c  168  8.648876  84.67477 19.036321
```

By applying `plot.zoo` i can plot one type a time like this:

```
> setkey(DT,type)
> plot(zoo(DT["a"])[,3:5])
```

But how can i plot all the products into one panel where different colors represents different types?

**EDITED:**
I think my original questions can be interpreted into 2 meanings: How to put "A","B","C" (different columns) into one panel and How to put "a" "b" "c" (different type value in rows) into one panel.
Both @Joshua Ulrich and @Paul Hiemstra have answered the first question but what i really want to know is the second one.
For better understanding i rename the colnames of DT

```
> names(DT)<-c("type","time","Attr1" ,"Attr2" , "Attr3"  )
> DT

   type time     Attr1     Attr2     Attr3
  1:    a    1  7.462817 119.91299  7.404987
  2:    a    2  7.733695 146.14601 -3.203601
  3:    a    3 19.034468  84.45497  9.623048
  4:    a    4  8.813990 123.21235 12.719920
  5:    a    5 16.803735  92.69359 11.393730
 ---                                        
500:    c  164 18.016771  90.29856 10.238281
501:    c  165  6.566802 131.67801 -2.085370
502:    c  166 20.031678  83.34749 12.261008
503:    c  167  4.705976 109.76303  9.327958
504:    c  168  8.648876  84.67477 19.036321
```

What i am looking for is a plot with 3 panels, each panel represent an ATTRIBUTE ("Attr1", "Attr2", "Attr3"), within each panel, there are several lines(time series) with different colors represent different types of data ("a","b","c")

Sorry for the previous misleading

Answer (score 2):

Use the `screens` and `col` arguments to `plot.zoo`:

```
plot(zoo(dt["a"][,list(A,B,C)]), screens=1, col=c('red','blue','green'))
```

[image]

Comment: I think i didn't make myself clear. What i want is not putting tree column data into one panel, but putting each column's data of dt["a"], dt["b"], and dt["c"] into one panel. so there will be three panels in the plot, each panel represents an attribute column and has different color of lines representing different type.  i will change the original question

Answer (score 0):

I am a big `ggplot2` fan, so I'll use that to solve your question. Note that I normally tend to stick to normal `data.frame`'s, and not `data.table` structures. Also, `ggplot2` requires the data structure to change a bit, I do that using `melt` from `reshape2`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df = as.data.frame(dt)
df_melt = melt(df, id.vars = c("type", "time"))
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = time, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I think i didn't made my question clear. I reedit the question so please check it again. Sorry for the misleading